# How to hide multiple elements with the hideElements argument in screenshot function of PhantomCSS

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, phantomjs, casperjs, phantomcss

How to include more than one element in hideElements argument in screenshot function?

For one element:

```
phantomcss.screenshot(target, timeOut, "div.page", fileName);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any jQuery selector as seen in the [code](https://github.com/Huddle/PhantomCSS/blob/681a2a27acada31176d1172d7cbe40f57f33ec19/phantomcss.js#L682). jQuery supports the comma operator that you should know from CSS selectors. Example:

```
phantomcss.screenshot(target, timeOut, "div.page, span.smth, .advertisement", fileName);
```

If you're unsure, just take a peek in the source code. That's the beauty of open source projects.